# How to set DTR/RTS state that will be used when CreateFile() opens COM port

Tags: c++, c, windows, serial-port

I wrote/support a terminal emulator called uCon (http://www.umonfw.com/ucon).  Its all based on "good-ole" Win32, and is entirely in 'C'.  I was recently asked to support the ability to have uCon attach to a COM port and set up DTR/RTS for purposes outside of RS232 flow control.  I know I can do this after CreateFile() is called using EscapeCommFunction() and/or SetCommState(); however, these functions can only be called AFTER CreateFile() returns a handle to the opened port.  Unfortunately, when CreateFile() opens the port, it sets DTR/RTS to their default state, which may (or may not) be different than the state that I wish to keep DTR in.

For example, assume the user has a board connected to the PC's serial port, and the DTR line is used to put the board in some non-standard state.  With DTR inactive, the board runs "normal", but occasionally DTR-active is used to transition the hardware to some other state.

In most cases I've seen, CreateFile() brings DTR active, then my call to clear DTR brings it back to inactive; however, that's a glitch I need to avoid.  I found a function set called GetDefaultCommConfig() & SetDefaultCommConfig() but have not been able to get them to work successfully.  So, my question is this...

Is there a way to pre-define the default state that will be established on the RS232 control lines when CreateFile() is called?  Has anyone used GetDefaultCommConfig()/SetDefaultCommConfig() successfully?

It seems to me that this should allow me to pre-establish the value of DTR to be
used when CreateFile() is called...

```
 
int
EstablishDefaultDTR(char *comPortName, int dtr)
{
    COMMCONFIG  cc;
    DWORD   bsize = sizeof(COMMCONFIG);

    if (GetDefaultCommConfig(comPortName,&cc,&bsize) == 0) {
        ShowLastError("GetDefaultCommConfig()");
        return(-1);
    }

    if (dtr)
       cc.dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE ;
    else
       cc.dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE ;

    if (SetDefaultCommConfig(comPortName,&cc,bsize) == 0) {
        ShowLastError("SetDefaultCommConfig()");
        return(-1);
    }
}
```

But, as you may have already guessed, it doesn't.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx  The article offers BuildCommDCB() as an alternative ... perhaps that will do the trick for you?

Comment: @Ed: I'm having the exact same problem. Could you solve it? I'm offering a bounty.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=291244 Same problem at hand. However TDM claims that setting the DTR to its state after opening the port is the only defined way to do so. If a 100ms switch lag kills the hardware than there is a design flaw right from the beginning.

Comment: @Bort: In my case, it doesn't kill it, it just makes an X-Ray tube spin uselessly, which should be avoided but isn't fatal. I agree with you, but anyway, the `MODE` solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Might not be the fastest way, but this works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
EstablishDefaultDTR(char *comPortName, int dtr){
    char commandString[256];
    if ( !system(NULL) ){
        ShowLastError("system()");
        return(-1);
    }        
    sprintf( commandString, "MODE %s dtr=%s%", comPortName, dtr? "on":"off"  );
    return system( commandString );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that just open the port and set the DTR state? If you have the port open already then the `MODE` command fails. The next time you open the port it keeps the previous state. You can get the same behaviour by opening a port, setting DTR, closing the port and then opening it again in code.

Comment: I do this before opening it and it works. I didn't check if the call to `CreateFile` succeeds, but the port is opened with the correct DTR state (before, it ALWAYS started with DTR set), and communication works as expected.

Comment: Even if I opened the port, cleared DTR, closed it and opened it again later, I could see the hardware reacting during the small period in which DTR was set (a led was lit and an xray tube spun for half a second). With this solution, that doesn't happen at all.

Comment: Observed: This MODE command indeed also fires a DTR impuls upon first usage (and thus resets an Arduino here on a freshly attached USB serial). Obviously just opens normally with CreateFile as well, sets fDtrControl=FALSE and Close()'s again - no solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're not initializing the COMMCONFIG structure.  That could well be the problem since the documentation explicitly says that you must set dwSize at least

cc.dwSize = sizeof( COMMCONFIG );

Comment: Just doing that before the first call didn't work. Both calls return nonzero, so, apparently, they succeed. After the call to `GetDefaultCommConfig`, I checked `cc`'s contents and the only weird thing I saw was that `cc.dcb.DCBLength` equaled `3435973836`. I'm gonna try using `BuildCommDCB` before the first call. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I found a workaround and posted it as an answer. I'll wait until the bounty expires to see if someone comes up with a better working solution.

Comment: @Danra: Nope. I tried to add my code to the question, but my edit was rejected. Basically, after declaring the `COMMCONFIG` and setting its size, I used `BuildCommDCB` to set its DCB. I tried doing that before `GetDefaultCommConfig`. After that call, I changed the struct contents to disable DTR before the call to `SetDefaultCommConfig`. I checked with the debugger and all the struct contents made sense all the way, but still the port always opened with DTR set. I also read somewhere that this way of doing it doesn't work with some devices, so I gave up and adopted the solution from my answer,

Comment: My "device" is a microcontroller someone else made as an interface to an X-Ray generator. I know little about the electronics part, I was just told what happens if I set or clear DTR and RTS, and I receive some data via Tx to notify certain events.

Comment: @Danra: Here's the [code](http://ideone.com/kdWiB) I tried with `BuildCommDCB`, perhaps you notice some mistake (aside from the obvious; it doesn't compile outside my test, I just put it there to share it)